# How to change cursor on graph data in jquery plot?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i want to change cursor style on mouse over of graph data in JQUERY PLOT plugin.

Comment: show us your code, and say us what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

You can do i with css:

```
.plotclass:hover {
    cursor: url('pathtocursor');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you want, but I think this will help you.

```
plot.bind("plothover", function(event, pos, item) {
    if(item) {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    } else {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    }
}
```